# Strange Oracle SQLPlus host echo error

Tags: oracle, environment-variables, sqlplus

I am trying to run a script.  We have 11.2.0.1 installed on most of our machines.  I was asked to upgrade to 11.2.0.3 on some of them.  I upgraded in my Windows environment locally on my Windows 7 box.  Everything worked fine.  Then I was given a virtual with Windows Server 2008 (not R2) 32 bit.  So, I downloaded the 32 bit client.

When I tried to run our script, I was getting some odd errors. I looked into it, and it turns out that SQL*Plus will not pass the environment variables

So, if I do `host echo %COMPUTERNAME%` I get a response of `%COMPUTERNAME%`

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you use "echo %COMPUTERNAME%" from the command line?  It might be a misconfigured VM. Are you using VMware?

Comment: If I type echo %COMPUTERNAME% from the command line, it gives me the name of the computer.  And yes, we're using VMWare, but it's centrally controlled, so I can't administer the box.

Comment: What happens if you just use "host" by itself? If it does open a command shell, which variables does "set" show?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this is because Oracle is having trouble with the `%`. There's no need to use the HOST command to do this though. You can use the `TERMINAL` parameter of the `USERENV` namespace for [`SYS_CONTEXT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions184.htm#SQLRF06117) instead:

```
SQL> select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'TERMINAL') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','TERMINAL')
---------------------------------------------------------

ELZAR
```

The documentation describes `TERMINAL` as:

> The operating system identifier for the client of the current session.
>   In distributed SQL statements, this attribute returns the identifier
>   for your local session. In a distributed environment, this is
>   supported only for remote SELECT statements, not for remote INSERT,
>   UPDATE, or DELETE operations. (The return length of this parameter may
>   vary by operating system.)

If you must use the HOST command I can get round the problem by enclosing in backticks

```
SQL> host `echo %computername`
ELZAR
```

Comment: "host echo %COMPUTERNAME%" works fine on my system without quotes.

Comment: It doesn't on mine @Chris or the OPs... The central part of my answer is that there is a way to do this in Oracle, without resorting to external OS commands though.

Comment: I currently have a project that has over 150 SQL scripts in it.  To change each one to have a different call when it is supposed to work, and in fact does on another machine, doesn't work for the environment.  I just need a way to fix my VM that has this problem.

Comment: You didn't put any of that in the question @paul... Personally, I would take the hit and change it as your current method is OS dependent when it needn't be.